# Could I choose a PhD supervisor from a different university?

Tags: phd, advisor, supervision

I want to apply for a PhD at a Canadian university, but I currently am in a Masters Program in the US. If I attend this new university, would I be able to choose a PhD supervisor from my current university?

Comment: If you want a supervisor from your current institution you want to attend a PhD program at your current institution, not elsewhere.

Answer (score 8):

It is very unlikely, probably impossible, that you could have a *primary* supervisor from another university, especially in a different country.

You also really need someone at your doctoral university to guide you through the rules and such of that university. Someone from the States wouldn't be very good at that.

However, some universities permit co-supervisors, so that might be a possibility. It would be easier if your primary supervisor has a professional relationship, already, with the person you would like from the States. It would be up to the primary (local) supervisor to agree to such a relationship.

And bad things can happen if it turns out that your various supervisors don't agree on things.

Comment: Not to mention the "ask" here of the local advisor is pretty big: "hey I don't *really* want to work with you, but could you help facilitate me working with who I actually want as my advisor?"

Answer (score 2):

It is technically possible to have 2 advisers, in which case one should be from the institution you are currently in and another can be from wherever you want. How exactly your interaction with them is organized concerns only the three of you but in the end both advisers should be confident signing the defense paperwork. I just had a colleague who left to another place and his student stayed. We agreed that I would become a second adviser and though I interacted with the student quite a lot (having a reading course with him, checking the progress, etc.), the main work on his dissertation was actually done with my former colleague. This was sort of a forced arrangement under the circumstances, but it can also be done from the start: we faced no formal objections when doing it. Whether somebody from your university will agree to work together with somebody else from a different university in that way is another good question, of course.

Answer (score -1):

I changed universities between my Masters (actually, German Diplom) and PhD. However, it was in the same country. And I knew my supervisor-to-be by attending her lectures – there was a collaboration of both universities.

So, a good idea might be to go to your preferred institution as an exchange student.

Else, all the other answers on choosing a supervisor on this site apply.

Oh, and the affiliation of the supervisor matters. A bit simplified, you cannot be a PhD student at one university and have a supervisor somewhere else. Exceptions mostly involve the *supervisor* moving out and are, basically, a recipe for disaster. Don't do this.